# Array storing javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array and i want to make different array for different values. this is my array

```
  var data = [{
      "rateType": "Fixed",
      "interestRateMin": "12.0",
      "imageUrl": "\/images\/dyn\/null.jpg",
      "financingPercentageMax": "80",
      "interestRateMax": "12.0",
      "prePaymentCharge": "Nil",
      "financingPercentageMin": "60",
      "bankName": "Muthoot Finance",
      "security": "Pledge of the gold ornaments and coins.",
      "repaymentTenureInYears": "0.25",
      "age": "35",
      "processingFee": "Nil",
      "maxLoanAmt": "10000000"
  },  {
      "rateType": "Floating",
      "interestRateMin": "12.5",
      "imageUrl": "\/images\/dyn\/94.jpg",
      "financingPercentageMax": "90",
      "interestRateMax": "12.5",
      "prePaymentCharge": "DNA",
      "financingPercentageMin": "75",
      "bankName": "Federal Bank- Gold loan",
      "security": "DNA",
      "repaymentTenureInYears": "1",
      "age": "35",
      "processingFee": "DNA",
      "maxLoanAmt": "7500000"
  },   {
      "rateType": "Floating",
      "interestRateMin": "13.0",
      "imageUrl": "\/images\/dyn\/155.jpg",
      "financingPercentageMax": "80",
      "interestRateMax": "13.0",
      "prePaymentCharge": "DNA",
      "financingPercentageMin": "80",
      "bankName": "State Bank of Travancore- Liquid loan",
      "security": "Pledge of gold ornaments",
      "repaymentTenureInYears": "1",
      "age": "35",
      "processingFee": "DNA",
      "maxLoanAmt": "1000000"
  }, {
      "rateType": "Floating",
      "interestRateMin": "13.25",
      "imageUrl": "\/images\/dyn\/151.jpg",
      "financingPercentageMax": "80",
      "interestRateMax": "13.25",
      "prePaymentCharge": "DNA",
      "financingPercentageMin": "80",
      "bankName": "State Bank Of Hyderabad- Overdraft",
      "security": "Pledge of Gold ornaments or Jewellery made of 22 Carat or 18 Carat",
      "repaymentTenureInYears": "3",
      "age": "35",
      "processingFee": "1.10% of the original limit or max Rs 330",
      "maxLoanAmt": "1500000"
  }, {
      "rateType": "Floating",
      "interestRateMin": "14.5",
      "imageUrl": "\/images\/dyn\/161.jpg",
      "financingPercentageMax": "80",
      "interestRateMax": "14.5",
      "prePaymentCharge": "DNA",
      "financingPercentageMin": "80",
      "bankName": "Lakshmi Vilas Bank",
      "security": "Pledge of gold ornaments",
      "repaymentTenureInYears": "1",
      "age": "35",
      "processingFee": "0.50% of the limit sanctioned, min Rs 100",
      "maxLoanAmt": "5000000"
  }];
```

I want to store all rateType in one array. Like this i want to make different array to store other elements. Can someone guide me on this

Comment: You what to iterate this array and create a new one with [rateType]  values?

Comment: Can you explain more? What should the new array contain?

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: I want to create a separate array for rateType and store all rateType values in it

Comment: i have updated the array. this is my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an array of the `rateType`s (for instance) in the `data` object, you can do this:

```js
var data=[{rateType:"Fixed",interestRateMin:"12.0",imageUrl:"/images/dyn/null.jpg",financingPercentageMax:"80",interestRateMax:"12.0",prePaymentCharge:"Nil",financingPercentageMin:"60",bankName:"Muthoot Finance",security:"Pledge of the gold ornaments and coins.",repaymentTenureInYears:"0.25",age:"35",processingFee:"Nil",maxLoanAmt:"10000000"},{rateType:"Floating",interestRateMin:"12.5",imageUrl:"/images/dyn/94.jpg",financingPercentageMax:"90",interestRateMax:"12.5",prePaymentCharge:"DNA",financingPercentageMin:"75",bankName:"Federal Bank- Gold loan",security:"DNA",repaymentTenureInYears:"1",age:"35",processingFee:"DNA",maxLoanAmt:"7500000"},{rateType:"Floating",interestRateMin:"13.0",imageUrl:"/images/dyn/155.jpg",financingPercentageMax:"80",interestRateMax:"13.0",prePaymentCharge:"DNA",financingPercentageMin:"80",bankName:"State Bank of Travancore- Liquid loan",security:"Pledge of gold ornaments",repaymentTenureInYears:"1",age:"35",processingFee:"DNA",maxLoanAmt:"1000000"},{rateType:"Floating",interestRateMin:"13.25",imageUrl:"/images/dyn/151.jpg",financingPercentageMax:"80",interestRateMax:"13.25",prePaymentCharge:"DNA",financingPercentageMin:"80",bankName:"State Bank Of Hyderabad- Overdraft",security:"Pledge of Gold ornaments or Jewellery made of 22 Carat or 18 Carat",repaymentTenureInYears:"3",age:"35",processingFee:"1.10% of the original limit or max Rs 330",maxLoanAmt:"1500000"},{rateType:"Floating",interestRateMin:"14.5",imageUrl:"/images/dyn/161.jpg",financingPercentageMax:"80",interestRateMax:"14.5",prePaymentCharge:"DNA",financingPercentageMin:"80",bankName:"Lakshmi Vilas Bank",security:"Pledge of gold ornaments",repaymentTenureInYears:"1",age:"35",processingFee:"0.50% of the limit sanctioned, min Rs 100",maxLoanAmt:"5000000"}];

var result = [];

data.forEach(function(element){
   this.push(element.rateType);
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

I've use the `thisArg` of a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to create a new array.

Cheers!